# How to extract Bills receivable data to excel from tally by ODBC?

Tags: odbc, data-export, tally

I am new to extracting data with ODBC Tally ERP 9.0. I researched and got some help with [Exracting Day Books / Transaction Data from Tally using ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53654205/exracting-day-books-transaction-data-from-tally-using-odbc)
Although this solution helps in some way it doesn't fully solves the problem. I want to get data in this format
Date 
Party's Ledger Name
Voucher No
Amount

This data should be filtered on only Outstanding Invoices (Invoices which are not paid by Sundry Debtors). The data should also include invoices of previous years (if the bill is outstanding it should be included irrespective of how many years in the past we have to go).

The above solution do addresses the issue getting those 4 columns. However,  it does not solve the issue mentioned in the above paragraph. Meaning I getting all the invoices pad or unpaid for the current year and I am getting the data for only the current year.Any help in this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a collection as below to get receivable bills of company.

```
[Collection: CMPRecevables]

    Type            : Bills
    Is ODBC Table   : YEs
    Filter          : IsReceivable
    Fetch           : Name, BillDate, Parent, ClosingBalance
```

connect this table using odbc and use below query

select $Name, $BillDate, $Parent, $ClosingBalance from CMPRecevables