# Export Receipts and Payment Details from Tally using Python

Tags: odbc, export, payment, receipt, tally

I am trying to export payment details in a below report format:

Date    Agst Ref    Party Name  Amount
11/25/2019  19-20/1256  ABC      4,145

[Extracting Day Books / Transaction Data from Tally using ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53654205/extracting-day-books-transaction-data-from-tally-using-odbc)

The answer in the above link solved 75% of my problem. I was able to extract Date, Party's Ledger Name and Amount. But I am struggling to export the 4th data point "Agst Ref" for both payment and receipt.

I am fine with sending XML export request if exporting it via ODBC route is not possible. In which case I need XML code.

Please assist me because I am stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Agst Ref is just $Reference. What do you get when you run the queries?

Comment: When I include $Reference in my SQL query all I get is a blank column with a header $Reference. Although in my Tally I have data for Agst Ref when I manually go and check both receipt and payment details